# In PyTorch, how can I avoid an expensive broadcast when adding two tensors then immediately collapsing?

Tags: python, pytorch, cosine-similarity, array-broadcasting, numpy-einsum

I have two 2-d tensors, which align via broadcasting, so if I add/subtract them, I incur a huge 3-d tensor. I don't really need that though, since I'll be performing a `mean` on one dimension. In this demo, I unsqueeze the tensors to show how they align, but they are 2-d otherwise.

```
x = torch.tensor(...)              # (batch , 1,  B)
y = torch.tensor(...)              # (1,    , A,  B)
out = torch.cos(x - y).mean(dim=2) # (batch, B)
```

Possible Solutions:

- An algebraic simplification, but for the life of me I haven't solved this yet.
- Some PyTorch primitive that'll help? This is cosine similarity, but, a bit different than `torch.cosine_similarity`. I'm applying it to complex numbers' `.angle()`s.
- Custom C/CPython code that loops efficiently.
- Other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save memory I recommend using [`torch.einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html):
We can make use of the trigonometric identity

```
cos(x-y) = cos(x)*cos(y) + sin(x)*sin(y)
```

In this case we can apply `einsum` where the usual summing will be the averaging, and the `+` between the two produces will be another operation later, so in short

```
xs, ys = torch.sin(x), torch.sin(y)
xc, yc = torch.cos(x), torch.cos(y)
# use einsum for sin/cos products and averaging sum, use + for sum of products: 
out = (torch.einsum('i k, j k -> i k', xs, ys) + torch.einsum('i k, j k -> i k', xc, yc)) / y.shape[1]
```

While measuring the memory consumption is a little bit tedious, I resorted to just measuring time as a proxy. Here you can see your original method and my proposal for various sizes of inputs. (The script for generating these plots is attached below.)

[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch
import time

def main():
    ns = torch.logspace(1, 3.2, 20).to(torch.long)
    tns = []; tes = []
    for n in ns:
        tn, te = compare(n)
        tns.append(tn); tes.append(te)
    plt.loglog(ns, tns, ':.'); plt.loglog(ns, tes, '.-'); plt.loglog(ns, 1e-6*ns**1, ':'); plt.loglog(ns, 1e-6*ns**2, ':'); plt.legend(['naive', 'einsum', 'x^1', 'x^2']);
    plt.show()

def compare(n):
    batch = a = b = n
    x = torch.zeros((batch, b)) # (batch , 1,  B)
    y = torch.zeros((a, b))  # (1,    , A,  B)
    t = time.perf_counter(); ra = af(x.unsqueeze(1), y.unsqueeze(0)); print('naive method', tn := time.perf_counter() - t)
    t = time.perf_counter(); rb = bf(x, y); print('einsum method', te := time.perf_counter() - t)
    print((ra-rb).abs().max()) # verify we have same results
    return tn, te

def af(x, y):
    return torch.cos(x - y).mean(dim=2) 

def bf(x, y):
    xs, ys = torch.sin(x), torch.sin(y)
    xc, yc = torch.cos(x), torch.cos(y)
    return (torch.einsum('i k, j k -> i k', xs, ys) + torch.einsum('i k, j k -> i k', xc, yc)) / y.shape[1]

main()
```